# Unable to connect Sybase via Nginx/php-fpm, yet okay with shell php execution

Tags: php, nginx, sybase

I have a php script which connect to sybase. In the shell (with either root/www/sybase), it runs well and able to connect to sybase:

```
    /usr/local/php/bin/php /www/test.php            ------STEP 1
```

Yet when i access it via browser:firefox http://[domain-name]/test.php, it is not working:

```
sybase_connect() /www/test.php:120 test: Failed to connect to TEST004 ---STEP 2
```

Am I missing some env setting for nginx? Please help.

- PHP and Nginx work fine, http://[domain-name]/index.php is good.
- PHP extension for sybase is installed (sybase_ct), confirmed okay by STEP 1.

Answer (score 0):

OKay I figured this out.
The problem is envs.
Need to set them manually in my php code.

```
    putenv ("SYBASE=/opt/sybase");
    putenv ("SYBASE_ASE=ASE-15_0");
    putenv ("SYBASE_OCS=OCS-15_0");
    putenv ("SYBASE_WS=WS-15_0");
    putenv ("SYBROOT=/opt/sybase");
    putenv ("SYBPLATFORM=linux");
    putenv ("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/freetds/lib");
    putenv ("LC_ALL=default");
    putenv ('PATH=\"/usr/local/freetds/bin:$PATH\"');
    putenv ("DSQUERY=LOCALHOST");
```

Modify key and values accordingly if using freeTDS.